# Compare and grab items attributes

Tags: python, compare, maya, getattr

I have 3 locators in my scene, eg.
Locator01 - localScaleY value of 1
Locator02 - localScaleY value of 2
Locator03 - localScaleY value of 3

Each with a varying value in its localScaleY. I had wanted to compare this 3 Locators' localScaleY values and grab the one which is the highest (in this case it will be Locator03)

```
yMax = []
for yValue in pm.ls('locator*'):
    yMax.append(getAttr (yValue +'.localScaleY'))
    yMaxValue = max(yMax)
    print yMaxValue
```

So based on the above coding, is it a viable way to write as I will be comparing more items? Or perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: Could you fix your indentation?

Comment: Could you put the `Locator`s in a list? Then it's just `max(l.localScaleY for l in locators)`.

Comment: This is confusing...what are all these terms? What are you actually trying to do? Can you provide some input data/output data?

Comment: @Bach Fixed the indentation, sorry about that, mush have accidently shifted it when I was pasting my code
@jonrsharpe What do you mean in a `list`? In the above example, Locators is just an example as the items I will be using, are mostly imported in-house but they are of the same type...
@mdscruggs The terms I used are derived from Autodesk Maya Python commands eg. `.localScaleY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a generator of scale/object tuples, and take the `max` of that. By putting the scale first, `max` keys off that correctly.

```
locators = ((getAttr(locator+'.localScaleY'), locator) for locator in pm.ls('locator*'))
yMaxValue, locator = max(locators)
```

A few outputs for reference:

```
>>> list(locators)
# Result: [(1.0, nt.Transform(u'locator01')),
           (2.0, nt.Transform(u'locator02')),
           (3.0, nt.Transform(u'locator03')),
           (1.0, nt.Locator(u'locator0Shape1')),
           (2.0, nt.Locator(u'locator0Shape2')),
           (3.0, nt.Locator(u'locator0Shape3'))] # 
>>> yMaxValue
# Result: 3.0 # 
>>> locator
# Result: nt.Locator(u'locator0Shape3') #
```

Comment: Cool, this works as well... Just wondering as compared to my version, could someone point to me where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: The biggest difference is you're getting the `max` on every iteration. Otherwise yours works for getting the biggest scale. It doesn't work for getting the locator *with* the biggest scale

Answer (score 0):

Whereas mhlester's answer works, I don't see the reason for a generator her. I would simply `max()` the list.

```
maxLoc = max(l.localScaleY for l in locs)
print '{} has the highest value in localScaleY: {}'.format(maxLoc.split('.')[0], maxLoc.get())
```

Comment: @ArgirlKotsaris Correct me if I am wrong but `format(maxLoc.split('.')[0]` wouldn't that mean getting the first item from the list? I test it out in my scene and it is indeed getting the first item which is wrong...

Comment: Only if the locator is needed, in addition to the value

Comment: And your `max` **is** consuming a generator too

Comment: I see, I shall go read up more on the generator part for better understanding. Thanks guys!